# O significado de uma delícia!

Tags: português-brasileiro

Quais significados tem **delícia**?

Algumas vezes pessoas usam para falar sobre uma criança:

> É uma delícia!

Algumas vezes sobre comida:

> Eu sempre faço sobremesa e ele a salada. Uma delícia.

Então o que é a significada numa palavra?

Comment: Suponho que você tenha procurado o(s) significados nos diversos dicionários.  O que você encontrou e com que dúvidas ficou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na língua portuguesa, temos uma propriedade chamada de *polissemia*. Ela trata da pluralidade significativa de uma palavra, que, conforme o contexto, tem um significado diferente.

O termo *delícia* é uma palavra polissêmica e seu significado vai depender do contexto, por exemplo:

1) Pode significar um *gosto bom*:

> A comida estava uma **delícia** / A comida estava *apetitosa*

2) Pode significar uma *sensação satisfatória, prazerosa ou agradável*:

> É uma **delícia** ser criança / Ser criança é *agradável*, *prazeroso*

3) Pode significar algo que traz *prazer; deleite*:

> A massagem tailandesa é **uma delícia**.

4) Pode significar uma pessoa que chama atenção pela *aparência; atraente, encantador*:

> Aquela pessoa é *uma delícia* / Aquela pessoa é *sexy*, sensual, bonita, atraente.

*Observação:* Nesse contexto, no entanto, é considerado vulgar.

5) Pode significar *alegria que se mantém*:

> *As delicias* de se fazer o que gosta.

---

A frase *"é uma delícia"* quando referida a uma criança, pode significar que ela a companhia dela agradável, prazerosa; mas — acredito eu — raramente verá essa frase. Ela também pode passar uma ideia sensual (ou seja, criminosa — a depender do contexto).

[Fonte](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6290.md)